# IBOutlet UIButton SIGABRT

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a created an IOS app to send email.  The issue I'm discovering is test my app on IOS simulator. When I tap my UIButton (IBOulet UIButton) I receive SIGABRT Error highlight classes in AppDelegate.swift file. There are no error codes displaying below. Also I have checked my oulet connections on view controller there are no exclamation points ("!") or existing duplicates.

```
@IBOutlet var Subject: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var Body: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()

    Subject.delegate = self
    Body.delegate = self
}


@IBAction func SendEmail (_sender: Any)
{
    let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self

    if let subjectText = Subject.text {
        picker.setSubject(subjectText)
    }
    picker.setMessageBody(Body.text, isHTML: true)

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    Body.text = textView.text
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()

        return false
    }
    return true
}



}
```

[Outlet Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXLE8.jpg)

[SIGABRT Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxMW0.jpg)

Comment: There’s no UIButton in your class. Also those IBOutlets should be weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` before presenting your `MFMailComposeViewController`. From [canSendMail()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/1616879-cansendmail) documentation:

> You should call this method before attempting to display the mail composition interface. If it returns false, you must not display the mail composition interface.

`canSendMail()` will return `false` if you didn't set up an email address for sending mail on your device.

Try:

```
@IBAction func SendEmail (_sender: Any)
{
    if(!MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {
        if let url = URL(string: "mailto:" + yourEmailAddress) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }

    let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self

    if let subjectText = Subject.text {
        picker.setSubject(subjectText)
    }
    picker.setMessageBody(Body.text, isHTML: true)
}
```

You check whether you can display `MFMailComposerViewController` and if not, you will open a `Mail` app

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where in my code I need to set MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()?